# select month year and date in date field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the value `$date='2017-10-30'` in my data table I have the field `requested_on` has `'2017-10-30 15:40:10'` I want to select the row using query.My query doesn't select the row which has the $date value

```
$reportdate =DB::table('asset_request')
 ->where('asset_request.requested_on','=',$date)->distinct()
 ->orderby('asset_request.request_id','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Either use LIKE and `'2017-10-30%'` for string comparison, or cast the column value to a DATE value first, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, You can use [whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) to compare a column's value against a date:

```php
$reportdate = DB::table('asset_request')
     ->whereDate('asset_request.requested_on', $date)
     ->distinct()
     ->orderby('asset_request.request_id','DESC')->get();
```